# JQuery DataTable - Search for exact match

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have looked at several other responses and tried them all but nothing works. I have the following in my table:

```
Date        Severity
2016-04-24  Not Critical    
2016-04-24  Critical [what I need returned]
2017-01-09  Not Critical    
2017-09-13  Critical
```

I am trying to search for all rows where severity is Critical (value) for 2016 (year). So far I have:

```
table.search(  year + " " + value ).draw();
```

This returns both rows for 2016. How can I get it to return just the row that I need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to enable and use regular expressions with [`search()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/search()) and [`column().search()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().search()) API methods.

Since you need to search two columns simultaneously, it may be better to combine two calls to [`column().search()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().search()).

For example:

```
table
  .column(0).search('2016')
  .column(1).search('^Critical$', true, false)
  .draw();
```

where `0` and `1` are indexes of your date and severity columns.

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/tm31y16b/1/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: what if I want to search two values in same column